# How to Strtotime in AJAX function? and error moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs

how to `strtotime()` in ajax?
i can create

```
var date = data[i].tanggal;
var newDate = moment(date).format('d-M-y');
tampil += "<td>"+ newDate +"</td>";
```

then error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: moment is not defined

then how to fix this code.

Comment: it seems you havn't added moment.js library

Comment: It seems you haven't searched yet for this error in google :)

Comment: If I were to *guess*, it sounds like `moment` is not defined.  Why specifically do you expect it to be defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
moment.tz(date,'Asia/Kolkata').toDate().format('d-M-y');
```

or

```
moment(date).format('d-M-y')
```

Comment: still error moment is not defined, i use js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js

Comment: Add required libraries of the moment js.

Comment: can be used. thank you